# Object error coming while using vba for cut paste code with cells function

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an object error on the following code

```
lc = Cells(11, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(11, lc - 6), Cells(70, lc)).Cut
Range(Cells(11, lc - 4)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Please advise

Comment: Well it looks like lc value could be one or two. This could lead to negative value of coulmn index in your Range Cut line.

Comment: Thanks. But I am facing the issue in the last two lines of the code. it is selecting the correct range but it is throwing an error while cutting and pasting. Please revert

Answer (score 0):

`lc` is probably negative. Write this to see:

```
lc = Cells(11, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
MsgBox lc
```

---

To make your code work, you have to pass `String` in the Select range. Currently, you are passing a cell, and you need to add its address:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim lc As Long
    lc = 10
    Range(Cells(11, lc - 6), Cells(70, lc)).Cut
    Range(Cells(11, lc - 4).Address).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

---

Last, but not least, `Select` and `Activate` are considered a bad practice. Once you feel more secure in your VBA knowledge, try to avoid them -  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score 0):

```
lc = Cells(11, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Range(Cells(11, lc - 6), Cells(70, lc)).Cut(ActiveSheet.Cells(11, lc - 4))
```

After Cut - you declare destination of cut cells. Suppose to work.